# VB.NET server not "launchable" after computer reboot

Tags: vb.net, server, console-application

I'm trying to learn how to code a server in VB.Net. I'm coding on Visual Studio.
My server works, my clients interact with it.

The thing is that if I reboot my computer, I have to make a new projet and copy/paste my code in order for my server to work.

If I don't do this my clients don't see my server.

I have no idea of why. If anyone have an idea I'll be very thankful.

Simon

Comment: are u developing the web project or windows application

Comment: I'm developping a windows console application.

Comment: so u create the solution file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find your exe file in your project folders and create a windows shortcut to it

On Windows 7 and earlier versions of Windows, the Start menu contained a “Startup” folder to make this easy. On these versions of Windows, you can simply open your Start menu, locate a shortcut to an application you want to start automatically, right-click it, and select Copy. Next, locate the Startup folder under All Apps in the Start menu, right-click it, and select Paste to paste a copy of that shortcut.

From [this site](http://www.howtogeek.com/228467/how-to-make-a-program-run-at-startup-on-any-computer/):

This folder is no longer as easily accessible on Windows 8, 8.1, and 10, but it’s still accessible. To access it, press Windows Key + R, type “shell:startup” into the Run dialog, and press Enter. Yes, you’ll need to use the folder — you can’t simply add shortcuts from the Task Manager’s Startup pane.

Shortcuts you add to the “shell:startup” folder will only launch when you log in with your user account. If you’d like a shortcut to launch itself whenever any user logs in, type “shell:common startup” into the Run dialog instead.